# Capistrano can not find action text css files whel precompilqing assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, hadoop-yarn, actiontext

I am using capistrano to deploy a rails 7.0.4.3 app. When I run `cap production deploy`
the service stops at this step:

`deploy:assets:precompile 01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

producing this error

```
01 rake aborted!
      01 Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'trix/dist/trix' with type 'text/css'
      01 Checked in these paths:
      01   /home/deploy/dynamic_performance/releases/20230530181802/app/assets/config
      01   /home/deploy/dynamic_performance/releases/20230530181802/app/assets/images
      01   /home/deploy/dynamic_performance/releases/20230530181802/app/assets/stylesheets
      01   /home/deploy/dynamic_performance/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/tailwindcss-rails-0.3.3/app/assets/fonts
      01   /home/deploy/dynamic_performance/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/tailwindcss-rails-0.3.3/app/assets/stylesheets
      01   /home/deploy/dynamic_performance/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/actiontext-7.0.4.3/app/assets/javascripts
      01   /home/deploy/dynamic_performance/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/actiontext-7.0.4.3/app/assets/stylesheets
      01   /home/deploy/dynamic_performance/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/actioncable-7.0.4.3/app/assets/javascripts
      01   /home/deploy/dynamic_performance/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activestorage-7.0.4.3/app/assets/javascripts
      01   /home/deploy/dynamic_performance/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.3/lib/assets/compiled
      01   /home/deploy/dynamic_performance/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/turbolinks-source-5.2.0/lib/assets/javascripts
.... truncated for brevity
```

I've read other post which say to run `yarn install --check-files` and `rails action_text:install` but that does not help. Action text works fine when I run `rails s` locally. How do I fix this error and compile my assets properly?

Answer (score 2):

That happened to me, here is what happens under the hood.
After upgrading to Rails 7.0, the task `rake assets:precompile` does not execute `yarn install`. That is why Sprockets can't find dependencies in `node_modules` folder. You can use the following code for this issue.

```
before "deploy:assets:precompile", "deploy:yarn_install"
namespace :deploy do
  desc "Run rake yarn install"
  task :yarn_install do
    on roles(:web) do
      within release_path do
        execute("cd #{release_path} && yarn install --silent --no-progress --no-audit --no-optional")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I guess it is an intended behavior of Rails 7.

Comment: In which file would this code go in? Capistrano or Rails?

Comment: Rails ofc, it is a new rake task

Comment: I am now receiving a no method error for before